# google compute engine match machine type to compute billing skus

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to programmatically match the machineType associated with a GCP compute instance to the corresponding billing SKU, but am unable to find a key for direct association. For example, here is the response from the machineType API:

```
{
 "kind": "compute#machineType",
 "name": "n1-standard-32",
 "description": "32 vCPUs, 120 GB RAM",
 "guestCpus": 32,
 "memoryMb": 122880,
 "imageSpaceGb": 0,
 "maximumPersistentDisks": 128,
 "maximumPersistentDisksSizeGb": "65536",
 "zone": "us-east1-b",
 "isSharedCpu": false
}
```

And here is the corresponding SKU from the cloudbilling APIs:

```
  "name": "services/6F81-5844-456A/skus/0E44-46AC-E398",
  "skuId": "0E44-46AC-E398",
  "description": "Standard Intel N1 32 VCPU running in Americas",
  "category": {
    "serviceDisplayName": "Compute Engine",
    "resourceFamily": "Compute",
    "resourceGroup": "N1Standard",
    "usageType": "OnDemand"
  },
  "serviceRegions": [
    "us-central1",
    "us-east1",
    "us-west1"
  ],
  "pricingInfo": [
    {
      "summary": "",
      "pricingExpression": {
        "usageUnit": "h",
        "usageUnitDescription": "hour",
        "baseUnit": "s",
        "baseUnitDescription": "second",
        "baseUnitConversionFactor": 3600,
        "displayQuantity": 1,
        "tieredRates": [
          {
            "startUsageAmount": 0,
            "unitPrice": {
              "currencyCode": "USD",
              "units": "1",
              "nanos": 520000000
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "currencyConversionRate": 1,
      "effectiveTime": "2018-02-22T12:00:16.647Z"
    }
  ],
  "serviceProviderName": "Google"
```

There doesn't seem to be a field with value `n1-standard-32` in the billing SKU. How do we tie these two together as this page seems to do: https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing?

Comment: You can use the description from the SKU => "description": "Standard Intel N1 32 VCPU running in Americas",

Comment: Thanks @Paula . That's the approach I've taken, though not preferable.

Comment: I would either use description ("Standard Intel N1 32 VCPU running in Americas") or resourceGroup ("N1Standard"), but I'm not 100% sure of your purpose, explain a little bit your use case so I can have a bigger picture of what you're trying to achieve.